# Application working fine on EC2 instance but not on ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tomcat7, amazon-elb

Application is not coming up on ELB but is coming up fine when tried on EC2 instance locally. 
I have created a new AMI with tomcat 7.0.70 installed and deployed my stack. But then ELB did not register instances on HTTPS:443 (using self signed cert using openssl). When changed healthcheck to TCP:443, the instances got registered over ELB (inService) but issue remains.

When tried to curl over load balancer url, it throws connection timed out. I have redirection set in tomcat's server.xml to redirect all http connections coming to EC2 instance to https as below:

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
              maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
              keystoreFile="yyy" keystorePass="xxx" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
              connectionTimeout="20000"
              redirectPort="443" />
```

No other configuration changes have been done and these setting have been working fine for all my old AMI's with tomcat 7.0.68. Nothing relevant is coming up in ELB Access logs.
Has anyone faced this issue before?

Appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Can you paste your ELB listeners how they are set up?

Comment: Load Balancer protocol - HTTPS
Load Balancer Port - 443
Instance protocol - 443
Instance Port -443
SSL Certfificate - my self signed cert

EC2 instance has inbound rule in SG to accept ELB SG for HTTPS over 443

Comment: Try changing this HTTPS Load Balancer Port - 80 from HTTPS Load Balancer Port - 443 and see if you can curl

Comment: So you have the SSL certificate configured in Tomcat, not on the ELB, correct? I think you need to change the listener on port 443 of the ELB from "HTTPS" to "TCP".

Comment: I tried all combinations:
Load balancer https over port 80 to instance https over port 443 => curl: (7) couldn't connect to host ;
Load balancer https over port 80 to instance http over port 80 => curl: (7) couldn't connect to host;
Load balancer https over port 443 to instance https over port 443 => curl: 408 Request timed out ;
Load balancer https over port 443 to instance http over port 80 => curl:  408 Request timed out ;

** I have the self signed certificate added on ELB

Comment: Are you trying to Curl the ELB Name over https?

Comment: This issue got fixed when I reverted back to tomcat version 7.0.68. I am not sure if there is any known issue with ELB not working with tomcat 7.0.70. I hope this doesn't have to do anything with my application using keystore as everything worked fine when using 7.0.68 tomcat version. Has anyone faced this issue with ELB when using 7.0.70 tomcat version?

Comment: Here is the clarification I got from AWS Tech support team:

Tomcat 7.0.70 seems to accept only ECDH ciphers which ELB client doesn't support at this time.

It appears that new Tomcat version (7.0.70) is enforcing/restricting the clients to use ECDH based ciphers.

Comment: Got a new update on this, This issue is only with Classic ELB but works fine with Application load balancer.

Comment: I had similar situation with tomcat 7.0.70 and I was able to overcome it by adding the following attribute to the 443 connector:
       ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"